# Compiling old C++ classes under Borland C++Builder XE

Tags: c++, c++builder

Currently, I'm working on compiling old .cpp classes under C++ Builder XE. Apart from many troubles, there is one which I have completely no idea how to solve.

My code:

```
String txt = "<Not so long sql query>";
int licz =  some_function(txt, dzeFDS);    //1
//assigning licz to somewhere
txt = "<much longer query>";
licz =  some_function(txt, budFDS);        //2
```

Problem is that during second call of `some_function` program is stopped and i have this alert:
`First chance exception at $75A1C42D. Exception class EDatabaseError with message 'budFDS: Type mismatch for field 'Function', expecting: String actual: WideString'. Process Call.exe (1896)`

It's strange form be, bacause first call of `some_function` works fine, but this second one (with arguments with the same type) doesn't.

`some_function` code:

```
int __fastcall some_function(String txt, TIBDataSet *firDS)
{
   firDS->Close();
   firDS->SelectSQL->Text = txt;
   firDS->Open();               //during debugging, exception occurs in this line

   int count = 0;
   while(!firDS->Eof)
   { count++;
     firDS->Next();
   }
   return count;
}
```

Any ideas what why it happens?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You're trying to put a WideString into a String. So converting your WideString to String should solve your problem.

Comment: What are `dzeFDS` and `budFDS`? Apparently `budFDS` wants a `String`. Not sure what the confusion is here.

Comment: But, as you can see, in the first call this is the same string as in the second, only it's value is changing, not type

Comment: Both `budFDS` and 'dzeFDS` are TIBDataSet. So is it possible, that `budFDS` need other type than `dzeFDS`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved - this one field `Function` has other type in C++ Builder design view - it was `TStringField`, and rest fields has `TIBStringField`...

Answer (score 1):

There is much pain in your future.

Anyway, the problem you're having is with the database connection. There's a field in your database called "Function" that holds a string. This field came across as a `String` with the ancient database driver that this program originally used. Your shiny, new database driver is telling VCL to expect such things as Unicode, and VCL doesn't like to shove such things into plain `String`s, so it expects you to have a `WideString` ready in which to shove it.

Fortunately, there are ways of beating VCL into submission. What you want to do, since you surely don't want to rewrite half the application by changing `TIBDataSet`, is to tell the connection not to bother with Unicode. In order to do this, you have to set up the `TSQLConnection` object with `UseUnicode=false`, which I hope (I have no way of testing VCL code anymore) should look something like this:

```
connection->Params->Add("UseUnicode=false");
```

Where `connection` is the `TSQLConnection` object. I think you have to do this before connecting to the database.

If that doesn't work, see if you can configure the database driver to not use Unicode.

Comment: "There is much pain in your future." True, I'm afraid...
You're really close - but i discovered, that the problem is that `Function` is a field in `budFDS` and it's related to one field in database, which is `smallInt`. Sad thing is that in my program `String` is expected, and from DB it's `WideString` (after `CAST(sth as varchar(10))`).  It's really strange for me, because other fields, which types in DB are also `varchar`s, are mapped to other fields without any problem.